# Unexpected behavior with pow function in library cmaths

Tags: c++, integer, double, typecasting-operator

I was solving the leetcode problem called excel sheet column number using c++. Please see the link for the question -> [Excel Sheet Column Number](https://leetcode.com/problems/excel-sheet-column-number/description/)
I came up with the following solution.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;
#define val(c) (static_cast<int>(c) - 64)

int titleToNumber(string columnTitle) {
    int result = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int n = columnTitle.length() - 1;
    while(n >=0){
        cout<<"Current value = "<<val(columnTitle[i])*(pow(26,n))<<endl;
        result = result + val(columnTitle[i])*(pow(26,n));
        cout<<"Result = "<<result<<endl;
        n--;
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
int main(){
string s  = "AA";
cout<<titleToNumber(s)<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

However, I am experiencing some unexpected error. I have initialized the value of **result** to **0** and when the program outputs the value of **Current value** it outputs it correctly which is **26**, but when it adds and assigns the value to the variable **result**, the value somehow becomes **25**.
I checked the type of the value returned from the expression **val(columnTitle[i])*(pow(26,n))** and it is of type **double**. I suspect that this is happening due to the type conversion from **double to integer**. However, the value of the expression is a whole number and does not have any floating part so there is no question of truncation. Also why the output value is **1** less than the expected?

*Typecasting the expression value to integer doesn't help.*

Can anyone please explain what is happening here and what I need to keep in mind in future for such conversions.
Thank you.

Please note that when I run my solution on online c++ compiler such ashttps://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler, the output is correct, but it is not correct when I run on my system. I am having **g++.exe (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0**  and I am also adding a snap of the output that I get.
[image: SNAP-output]

Comment: I get `Current value = 26
Result = 26` The next iteration of the loop is not what I expect but that's another question.

Comment: The problem is that you're expecting `pow(26, x)` to be exactly an integer - there is no integral exponential in the standard library and you need to write your own (and look out for overflow).

Comment: Yes on online compilers, it works fine but not on my pc.

Comment: I suspect this is MinGW defect. I cannot reproduce this on any version of GCC, clang or MSVC I can get my hands on with any combination of optimisation/standard flags.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot I am having g++.exe (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0

Comment: Make your life simple and use `std::round`.

Comment: Yah, I cannot get this behavior on pure GCC 6.3.0. GCC 6.3.0 is also ancient. I suggest switching either to MSVC or MinGW-w64 compiler.

Comment: @SatishSingh None of this requires any floating point functions.  Regardless of the compiler, your solution of using `pow` is broken.  Are you going to change compilers if you later find out that `pow` gives you other issues?  Do not use floating point functions to solve integer-based problems.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie. Thnax. Changing the pow function solves it.